# Keep increasing rep thresholds

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should reputation requirements change as a Stackoverflow Knowledge Exchange site grows in users and content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4497/should-reputation-requirements-change-as-a-stackoverflow-knowledge-exchange-site)

Once a user gets a privilege on stackoverflow at a particular rep threshold, They get it for life. Even if they dont remain active on the site any more.

I suggest they dont deserve to keep the privilege If they dont keep participating. So I suggest we keep increasing the rep threshold for various tools at a slow and steady rate. like  maybe 1 rep per day. Doesnt have to be calculated every day. Maybe weekly or monthly.

How about it

Answer (score 6):

If they don't keep participating... isn't that really just the same as if they didn't have the privileges?

Comment: +1 Now THAT is reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

Reputation is giving you moderating powers, gradually. These ones are awarded because according to the reputation you have, the time you spent on the site, you understand the way it works, and you have the knowledge and """responsibility""" to use these tools.

The fact that more and more people gain more experience changes nothing to this "learning the way it works" phase. I see no reason to increase the cost for them.

Increasing cost for these tools with time would be like saying that someone who comes now has to prove twice more that he is responsible enough to edit a post, or vote to close. Makes no sense.

Comment: Yes they should work harder. We already have an army of mods. As the number rises, the demand lessens and standards go up. You have to be truly exceptional if you want to make your place among a saturated group

Comment: @Midhat - It doesn't matter if we have an "army of mods". What matters is qualification, ability of people to do that. There is no reason new people should "work harder". It would only exclude them, making it harder for them to actually help the site by moderating. It's like putting a barrier "we were here first, we are enough, now beat it". There is NO advantage in discouraging new people to participate actively by rising the bar.